# Cannot read the property of id undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, typeerror

I'm making a website where you can share campground photos. And when someone makes a comments I want only comment's owner to see delete and edit options.

I've made an model for comment and made an author object that includes comment's owner's id and username. But when I try to get the owner's ID from that author object it returns undefined also if I try to get data by find method and write Comment.author.id it returns syntax error and says Unexpected token "."

That's my comment model.

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author:{
        username: String,
        id: String,
    }
});
```

That's the campground route

```
Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundCampground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            //render show template with that campground
            console.log(foundCampground.comments);
            User.findById(req.user._id, (err, user)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log(foundCampground.comments._id);
                    Comments.find({Comments.author.id: foundCampground.comments._id}, function(err, comment){
                        var authID = foundCampground.author.id;
                        var userID = user._id;
                        var commentID = comment.author.id;

                        console.log("Comment Id " + commentID);
                        console.log("UserID "+userID);
                        res.render("campgrounds/show",{campground: foundCampground, authID: authID, userID: userID});
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Same thing worked for the campground model

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }],
    author: {
        id: String,
        user: String,
    }
});
```

I expect to get the user id from comment.author.id but I get undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to replace `Comments.find({Comments.author.id: foundCampground.comments._id}` with `Comments.find({"author.id": foundCampground.comments._id}`.

Comment: this worked but when I try to get the author id it still returns Cannot read the property of id undefined altough it gets the true data. do you know how to fix that

Comment: I solved it problem by comment.forEach and getting the each comment's id.